# Loop three conditions in R

Tags: r

I'm sorry if I put wrong title, I'm new to coding, I apologize for any inconvenience.
I want to compare each value in nutl to range of values in fj.en, the output should return: if value falls within 4 to 7 out should print within limit, if value larger than 7 then it should return excessive, if smaller then it should output insufficient.
I know I cannot hold vector comparison for its internal data, but how can I force it to do so?
I tried the follwoing:

```
nutl<-c(7,3,5,6,10,5,6)
nutl
fj.en <- c(4:7)
fj.en
for (refnut in nutl) {
    if (refnut == fj.en) {
    print ("winthin limit")
    if (refnut > fj.en) {
    print ("excessive")
    }
    else {
    print ("insufficient")
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: (1) I tend to find `if`/`else` with nothing but `print` statements to be a general waste of time: you go through all of that effort, and nothing you've done is stored anywhere or otherwise usable outside of a human reading the console. (Nested `if` statements can be useful, but ... they need to *do* something else.)

Comment: (2) `if` requires a conditional of length exactly 1, and none of yours are like that. When I ask you *"is 4 equal to 3, 4, 5, 6"*, you may reply something like *"it equals one of them"*; from there, one should then consider using `any`, `all`, `%in%`, or some other logic. I'd suggest something more specific, but it's not clear to me what your goal is here.

Comment: Perhaps you just want `ifelse(refnut == fj.en, "within limit", ifelse(refnut > fj.en, "excessive", "insufficient"))`?

Comment: @r2evans I just updated what is the goal, thank you for pointing out that I should clarify the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to attack this problem, with a `for` loop being the least efficient. R really "rewards" doing things whole vectors at a time, so the first three take advantage of "vectorization":

1. Since you're looking at a specific length of values (the `range` of `fj.en`), then we can use `findInterval` or `cut` (here):

   ```r
   as.character(cut(nutl, c(-Inf, range(fj.en), Inf), labels = c("insufficient", "within limit", "excessive")))
   # [1] "within limit" "insufficient" "within limit" "within limit" "excessive"   
   # [6] "within limit" "within limit"
   ```
2. You can pre-populate a `character` vector and fill them in manually:

   ```r
   out <- character(length(nutl))
   out[ nutl < min(fj.en) ] <- "insufficient"
   out[ nutl > max(fj.en) ] <- "excessive"
   out[ !nzchar(out) ] <- "within limit"
   out
   # [1] "within limit" "insufficient" "within limit" "within limit" "excessive"   
   # [6] "within limit" "within limit"
   ```

   The `!nzchar(.)` function looks for zero-length strings. `character(.)` prepopulates a vector of `""` (zero-length) strings to the length requested, so we know that the first two reassignments assigned strings with more than 0 chars, so `!nzchar` worked. It would also have been okay to do

   ```r
   out[ min(fj.en) <= nutl & nutl <= max(fj.en) ] <- "within limit"
   ```
3. While I generally don't like nesting `ifelse` much, two-deep isn't a huge problem:

   ```r
   ifelse(nutl < min(fj.en), "insufficient",
          ifelse(nutl > max(fj.en), "excessive", "within limit"))
   # [1] "within limit" "insufficient" "within limit" "within limit" "excessive"   
   # [6] "within limit" "within limit"
   ```
4. Finally, the brute-force `for` loop.

   ```r
   out <- character(length(nutl))
   for (ind in seq_along(nutl)) {
     if (nutl[ind] < min(fj.en)) {
       out[ind] <- "insufficient"
     } else if (nutl[ind] > max(fj.en)) {
       out[ind] <- "excessive"
     } else out[ind] <- "within limit"
   }
   out
   # [1] "within limit" "insufficient" "within limit" "within limit" "excessive"   
   # [6] "within limit" "within limit"
   ```

I am demonstrating another recommendation: *store* the values (in a pre-allocated vector, if needed) and then determine if you want to `print` them.